# Visual Studio 2012 with Resharper, new DI Goto delclaration issue

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dependency-injection, resharper

When I am using "Go to Declaration" it takes me to the interface which is what the vs knows to be the type. My question is If there is a way to let the visual studio know that the my interface is bind only to a certain class and by that the "Go to Declaration" will take me to the specific method and not to it's interface.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty easy to configure it back. Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard and type i.e *ReShaperGotoImp*. You will find the command. Simply remove the existing once and re-assign the F12. If the F12 has been assigned to another command, it should also tell you. Goto that command remove the F12 and assign a different shortcut. Then come back to the  *ReShaperGotoImp* and assign F12.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure the OP is having a customization issue.

Comment: @Spock I think I was misunderstood. When I am using "Go to Declaration" it takes me to the interface which is what the vs knows to be the type. My question is If there is a way to let the visual studio know that the my interface is bind only to a certain class and by that the "Go to Declaration" will take me to the specific method and not to it's interface.

Comment: Ah ok sorry I thought you after general customization. Actually a good question. As far as I know I don't think there is a built-in approach to what you after.